# Generics not working with implicitly unwrapped optional

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I created an extension of UIView to be able to create and add a subview in one line:

```
extension UIView {

    func createAndAddSubview<T:UIView>() -> T {
        let view = T()
        self.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }
}
```

This works with normal declarations:

```
let myLabel:UILabel = view.createAndAddSubview()
var myImageView:UIImageView = view.createAndAddSubview()
```

But with implicitly wrapped optionals I get a compiler error. I think it's because the optional prevents the compiler from determining the correct type.

> 'UIView' is not convertible to 'UILabel'

```
class MyController {
    var myLabel:UIlabel!

    func foo() {
        myLabel = view.createAndAddSubview()
    }
}
```

Of course I can get it to work like this

```
let myLabel:UILabel = view.createAndAddSubview()
self.myLabel = myLabel
```

But this isn't one line anymore... how can I improve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting

Comment: Sorry. I get "'UIView' is not convertible to 'UILabel'". Added it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess compiler cannot infer the type as its `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`. Try:

```
self.myLabel = .Some(self.view.createAndAddSubview())
```

or

```
extension UIView {
    func createAndAddSubview<T:UIView>() -> T? {
        let view = T()
        self.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Just edited my question with the same assumption, but didn't know how to solve it. This fixed it - thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way to create another extension method that somehow includes the optional in the type declaration, such that I don't have to call .Some. But having difficulties figuring it out, at least it doesn't seem to work to use enums in type parameters... (Some is a case of ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional enum)

Comment: Concerning the last edit, I don't want to have to cast... it's why I'm using generics...

Comment: @Ixx Ok, you can return optional generic from the method.